# directory package : Using both directory and bibliography

Tags: bibtex, addresses

Anybody ??

I would like to generate a document that contains both an address book and bibliography (each as a chapter) using the [directory package](https://ctan.org/pkg/directory).
I tried unsuccessfully to follow what's indicate [here](http://geuz.org/directory/#tth_sEc4)
Can someone give me one functional example ? Is there any tip for compiling ?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the package before, but your question got me curious. I've only just begun to play around with it, but here's what I've been able to figure out.

Using it to create a directory in the same document in which you also use bibtex for the bibliography is a *very* involved process. This is in part because the package uses BibTeX and .bib files for a nonstandard purpose under the hood, and it's not possible to use BibTeX both its way and the regular way *in the same pass*.

I assume you know more or less how BibTeX works. The first run of LaTeX writes the citation data (via `\cite`), style data (via `\bibliographystyle`) and names of bib files used (via `\bibliography`) to the `.aux` file. BibTeX is run on the `.aux` file to create the bibliography as a `.bbl` file. Then LaTeX is run two more times: first to insert the `.bbl` file into the document and then again link up its bibliographical items to the citations.

It's useful to think of how the directory package's commands replace the BibTeX ones:

- commands like `\dir{...}` are a layer on top of citation commands like `\cite{...}` and replace them
- `\directorystyle{...}` is a layer on top of `\bibliographystyle{...}` and replaces it
- `\directory{...}` is built on top of the `\bibliography{...}` command; this command both sets the names of the `.bib` files used for the directory, and sets the placement of the directory

So here's an example workflow to use BiBTeX both ways. Some notes on my example:

- In my example, I use the book class, since you mentioned chapters, so we need a document class with chapters. I assume this doesn't matter much.
- I load directory with the break option but you'll want to read the documentation to see what options you need.
- I'm using the package's example `family.bib` and `business.bib` files for the directory entries. These came installed in my TeXlive distribution at `/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/directory`, but you can also download and extract them from the [tarball]((http://www.geuz.org/directory/src/directory-1.20.tgz) from the page you linked to at geuz.org, which also contains them. You'll need to create similar files for your directory items.
- The `xampl.bib` is just a example .bib file with regular bibliographical data; it's on my TeXlive distribution at `/usr/share/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/base`, but you can substitute your own, or use a different style than plain (maybe?)

Let's start with this document:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[break]{directory}
\directorystyle{address}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Normal Chapter}

In this chapter, we will refer to \dir{d.e.knu}---someone in the directory.

And then we will a paper: \cite{article-full}.

\chapter*{Directory}

% Use these if you want to include *everything* in the bib files
\nodir{*}
%\nocite{*}

\directory{family,business}
%\directory[dir]{xampl}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
%\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Here we have both directory commands and bibliography commands. I've commented out the bibliography commands, however, because we will first complete the directory. You can't have multiple bibliography styles (the directorystyle counts) or different bibliography databases enabled at once with standard BibTeX, so the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands are commented out while we do the directory steps.

I have `\nodir{*}` here which will include *all* the entries inside the two .bib files named by `\directory`: `family.bib` and `business.bib`, even the ones that aren't "cited". This is optional.

Compile the document with LaTeX once. All your "references" will be undefined, but this will populate the .aux file with the info needed for the directory-creating BibTeX run.

Now run BibTeX on the .aux file. BibTeX will give you a warning about missing database entries for the regular citations (e.g., here, "article-full"). But it will create the directory with the entries it does find from the directory database files and save it as a .bbl file.

Run LaTeX two more times. The directory should now be a part of the document located where the `\directory` command appears, and the `\dir` citations should appear correct. You'll still have question marks for the regular citations and no regular bibliograpy.

Now rename the `.bbl` file to have a different extension. The documentation suggests `.dir`. So `filename.bbl` is now `filename.dir`. This file contains all the directory contents.

Delete any other auxiliary files created by the previous steps.

Now we need to switch to working on the bibliography, so we comment out the `\directorystyle` command, and the `\nodir` command. We switch the `\directory` command to have an optional argument `[dir]` which tells it to look for the directory as a `.dir` file rather than a `.bbl` file. However, since this command still writes to the `.aux` file with the names of the `.bib` files it's supposed to use, we change the argument to `xampl` to use the regular `.bib` file. BibTeX will get confused otherwise.

Finally we uncomment the `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands. If we want to include everything in the new `.bib` file, we can uncomment/use the `\nocite` line.

Our document now looks like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[break]{directory}
%\directorystyle{address}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A Normal Chapter}

In this chapter, we will refer to \dir{d.e.knu}---someone in the directory.

And then we will a paper: \cite{article-full}.

\chapter*{Directory}

% Use these if you want to include *everything* in the bib files
%\nodir{*}
\nocite{*}

%\directory{family,business}
\directory[dir]{xampl}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}

\end{document}
```

Run LaTeX again. Now the `.aux` file will have what BibTeX needs for the regular citations.

Run BibTeX on the `.aux` file. You may get error messages about having multiple bibdata commands (commands in the aux file telling it what bib file to use) since you have both `\directory` and `\bibliography` in the same file, but I'm not sure that can be helped. It should however create a new `.bbl` file, this time with the bibliography.

Run LaTeX two more times. Now you have both a directory and a bibliography. Congrats.

You'll have to do it all over again if you ever add to the directory.

Was it worth it? Probably not.

This isn't an opinion based site, but in your shoes I would strongly consider going a different route than using this crazy system, especially if you haven't already invested the time in converting your directory info to this strange .bib format. Maybe the process could be scripted, but even that wouldn't be easy.

If you have your directory information as a .csv file, consider using something like [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en) to create your directory instead of using this package with bibtex. Consider also using lua scripting with lualatex if you can, e.g., using a lua json package to read a json version of your directory information and insert the appropriate entries with raw LaTeX commands. Do some other kind of scripting externally to create LaTeX markup from your directory. Anything to avoid this absurd misuse of BibTeX.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
When using csvsimple to do so, do you know if it is possible to reference a name of the directory?
 For example:  "Please contact Mr Abraham Lincoln (see address book page xxx)". 
Something alike `\useentry{〈label〉}{〈field〉} ` of datatool package ?

Comment: You could probably put something like that together by using csvsimple in conjunction with something like cleverref. I'm not that familiar with it myself, but I think might be able to use datatool itself to do everything.